# Factory object causes stackoverflowexception due to dependancy upon itself

Tags: c#, factory-pattern, circular-dependency

I have a c# factory object which creates objects through factory methods, using a list of objects as a source.

The list of objects is created like this:

```
public WidgetFactory()
    {
        widgetLibrary = new List<WidgetModel>();

        //Add all widgets
        widgetLibrary.Add(new ClientsWidget());
        widgetLibrary.Add(new InstallationsWidget());
        etc.
```

and various parts of my application access this list in different ways to get the type of object it needs.

But I now have a requirement that one of the objects in the list(i.e. a widget) needs to make use of the widget factory itself. Clearly this causes a circular reference.

How can I alter my design to accomodate this need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I now have a requirement that one of the objects in the list(i.e. a widget) needs to make use of the widget factory itself. Clearly this causes a circular reference.
>
> How can I alter my design to accomodate this need?

Typically, objects should not rely on the factory that creates them for construction, as it causes exactly this problem.  If you can push in the reference to the factory, but not use it until it's needed, it may solve the issue.

If you absolutely need to do this, then the best approach may be to lazily instantiate the objects within the factory.  Instead of having your `WidgetFactory` contain a `List<WidgetModel>` internally, you could use a `List<Lazy<WidgetModel>>`.  This would allow the individual "widgets" to only evaluate as needed, which would mean that, when the widget in question tries to reference the factory, it'll be fully loaded.

Comment: The first idea worked, I just needed to be a bit more careful with making use of the factory in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> But I now have a requirement that one of the objects in the list(i.e. a widget) needs to make use of the widget factory itself. Clearly this causes a circular reference.
>
> How can I alter my design to accomodate this need?

Your model is wrong. Once a car has left the assembly line at the NUMMI plant, it doesn't depend on the plant to operate properly.

Also, I question the design of your factory. Why are you `new` instances the constructor. What purpose is that serving?

You should probably tell us a little bit more about your model and why you think you need this. Odds are, properly done, you don't.

Comment: Using this analogy, the object being prodcued is another car factory. This factory is creating models for UI elements, but I now need to create a UI element which maps to the factory. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jon Eastwood: Sounds like this one factory is doing too much (building factories and UI widgets?). You should separate out the responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for the WidgetFactory should not be calling the constructers of the things that it is building. Instead, the WidgetFactory should have a method (`BuildWidgets`) that does all of the work.

Then the other objects can make some use of the factory without causing this cascade of activity to start over again.

Comment: I agree with this, I think this is the root of the problem, but I'm not sure how to change it. I need a way of enumerating the possible types of objects the factory can create, without having to explicitly code build methods for each one.

Answer (score 0):

For starters,  move Widget creation out of the WidgetFactory's constructor. This should happen either in an initialization method or on-demand in a CreateWidget(Type) method.

To make the factory instance available to the Widget instances, you can do one of a few different things:

1. Have WidgetFactory pass 'this' when it creates the Widget
2. Use the singleton pattern: add a static property WidgetFactory.Instance and initialize it once; have all WidgetFactory users access the property rather than create a new instance.
3. Use the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern -- difficult to provide a short description here.

Comment: Sorry, are you just throwing some buzzwords out hoping that one of them is right?

Comment: @Jason ha! no, but I see why you say that. Both approaches are valid solutions to OP's problem, but I suppose my answer could use more detail.